# Error where () statement in google Adwords

Tags: vb.net, google-ads-api

Could you please help me to correct this statement:

```
Dim query As ReportQuery = New ReportQueryBuilder() _
         .Select("Id",
                "Date",
                "AllConversionRate",
                "AllConversions",
                "AllConversionValue",
                "AverageCpc",
                "AverageCpm",
                "BenchmarkAverageMaxCpc",
                "BenchmarkCtr",
                "Clicks",
                "ConversionRate",
                "Conversions",
                "ConversionValue",
                "Cost",
                "CostPerAllConversion",
                "CostPerConversion",
                "CrossDeviceConversions",
                "Ctr",
                "Impressions",
                "SearchAbsoluteTopImpressionShare",
                "SearchClickShare",
                "SearchImpressionShare",
                "ValuePerAllConversion",
                "ValuePerConversion",
                "ViewThroughConversions") _
         .From(ReportDefinitionReportType.PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT) _
         .During(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.LAST_7_DAYS) _
         .Where("Impressions" Or "Clicks" Or "Conversions" Or "AllConversions").GreaterThan(CType(0, Long)) _
        .Build()
```

I got this error "'Conversion from string "Impressions" to type 'Long' is not valid'"  after adding 'Or' between the attributes.
I tried to get the values from the columns of Adwords but they should one of them be bigger than zero 
Thanks.

Comment: How could you possibly compare the string "Impressions" with a number? You will have to show a bit more of your code to get help.

Answer (score 0):

OR operator is not supported in the AWQL.
so it is better to  parse the row that contains values of the attributes and then we can make a comparing.

```
 dim Impressions As Long = Nothing  
 Dim Clicks As Long = Nothing  
 Dim Conversions As Double= Nothing
 Dim AllConversions As Double= Nothing
Using response As ReportResponse = reportUtilities.GetResponse
                    Using gzipStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(response.Stream,
                                                                CompressionMode.Decompress)
                        Using reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(gzipStream)
                            While reader.Read
                                Select Case reader.NodeType
                                    Case XmlNodeType.Element ' The node is an Element.
                                        If reader.Name = "row" Then
                                            While reader.MoveToNextAttribute
                                                  Select Case reader.Name
                                                       Case "impressions"
                                                          Impressions = reader.Value
                                                       Case "conversions"
                                                        Conversions = reader.Value
                                                       Case "clicks"
                                                        Clicks = reader.Value
                                                      Case "allConv"
                                                       AllConversions = reader.Value
                                                  End Select
                                            End While
                      If Impressions + Clicks + Conversions + AllConversions > 0 Then
                         ''Do your stuff
                      End If
                                        End If
                                End Select
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
```